# How to set common img srcs in HTML to work across ASPx Pages in directories?

Tags: asp.net, image, url, path

I have a site with a page tree like this

```
/MySite/MyPage1.aspx
/MySite/MyDir/MyPage2.aspx
```

I also have an `img` directory in the root of the web project.

For common controls (i.e. the master page), if I use an img with path /img/myimage.png it works on MyPage1.aspx but not on MyPage2. I guess this is not resolving to the img folder from the root of the project.

How do I fix this?

(I do not want to use ~ to resolve to the file system location of the image because not all images are running as server side components)

Answer (score 0):

Use `../` to select the parent directory:

`../img/myimage.png`

Comment: Thank you - however, how do I make it work for pages such as the master page, or controls that are common to all pages, say menus etc.? That is my main issue (which wasn't clear in the original question)

Comment: Doesn't `/` take you to the project's root folder? That way you could use `/img/myimage.png` anywhere.

Comment: That's what I thought! But it doesn't work on /MySite/MyDir/MyPage2.aspx